# Создание анимации на элементе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какой то ступор. Пытаюсь скопировать определенный эффект на блоке, но все равно как то не так получается.
Буду очень благодарен за какие либо идеи)

Эффект с данного сайта http://xn----7sbabhc4cc2f.xn--p1ai/

Вот на этих блоках

[image: Блоки с эффектом]

Comment: Добавьте свои попытки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ответ изменен.**

Тут в CSS ключевой роли играет часть со `scale`

Вот это

```
transform: scaleY(1);

transform: scale(0);
```

Таким образом они там манипулируют картинками при ховере.

```css
.product_list_item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

.product_list_item .mask, .product_list_item .content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 235px;
    line-height: 235px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.overlay {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
.product_list_item .product_list_item_img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 235px;
}

.product_list_item a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 35;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product_list_item a.info: hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.product_list_item .product_list_item_img {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.product_list_item .mask {
    background-color: #96b94b;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.product_list_item .mask .product_list_item_title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0px 40px 15px 40px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    color: #000;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.product_list_item .mask .product_list_item_descr {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    max-width: 420px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    color: #000;
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.product_list_item a.info {

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.product_list_item:hover .product_list_item_img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);
    -moz-transform: scale(10);
    -o-transform: scale(10);
    -ms-transform: scale(10);
    transform: scale(10);
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.product_list_item:hover .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.product_list_item:hover .mask .product_list_item_title,
.product_list_item:hover .mask .product_list_item_descr, .product_list_item:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="product_list_item">
  <div class="product_list_item_img" style="background:url('https://wallscloud.net/uploads/cache/2168525702/brie_larson_as_captain_marvel-1024x576-MM-90.jpg')  no-repeat 0% 0%; background-size:cover;">
    <a href="#" class="overlay">
      <div class="product_list_item_caption">
          <div class="product_list_item_background">
              <div class="product_list_item_title">BLA BLA BLA BLAAAAA</div>
              <div class="product_list_item_descr">Bla bla bla bla bla</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="mask" style="background:url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/477/thumb-1920-477856.jpg') repeat 0% 0%,url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/09/13/32/fantasy-3664586_960_720.jpg') no-repeat 0% 0%;
background-position: center; background-size:cover;">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="product_list_item_title">BLA BLA BLA BLA</div>
            <div class="product_list_item_descr">BLA BLA BLA BLAAAAA</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))
Вроде догнал)

Comment: @Избыток сусликов не-а это я догнал (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо большое

Comment: @АланАлеков если вопрос решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку наверху.